# jQuery problems in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking for a fly to cart effect and I got this one that works fine in Chrome but not so good in Firefox. Can somebody help me to fix this one? The effect doesn't appear to look fine in Firefox but in Chrome it works great.

If somebody needs the page to test it try this:
http://mundobodega.com/depositos-de-vino-fermentadores-ino

```
function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {    
    var $func = $(this);   
    var divider = 3;   
    var flyerClone = $(flyer).clone();   
    $(flyerClone).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(flyer).offset().top + "px", left: $(flyer).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});   
    $('body').append($(flyerClone));   
    var gotoX = $(flyingTo).offset().left + ($(flyingTo).width() / 2) - ($(flyer).width()/divider)/4;   
    var gotoY = $(flyingTo).offset().top + ($(flyingTo).height() / 2) - ($(flyer).height()/divider)/4;   

    $(flyerClone).animate({
        opacity: 0.4,
        left: gotoX,
        top: gotoY,
        width: $(flyer).width()/divider,
        height: $(flyer).height()/divider
    }, 700,
    function () {
        $(flyingTo).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(flyingTo).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(flyerClone).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(flyerClone).remove();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

 $(document).ready(function(){         
     $('.addtocart').on('click',function(){    
        //Scroll to top if cart icon is hidden on top    
        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop' : $("#vercesta").position().top
        });
        //Select item image and pass to the function    
        var itemImg = $('.img0');
        flyToElement($(itemImg), $('#vercesta'));
    });    
});
```

Comment: where is it on the test page ?

Comment: @WalleCyril It's the red button towards the end that reads *Añadir a la cesta* on it. Took me a while to figure out too

Comment: Sorry to everybody, I always forget somenthing... @WalleCyril is right! the red button towards the end that reads Añadir a la cesta (means add to cart in spanish)